# Quadratic form of a trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, trace

> Let $V := \left\{ X \in \mathfrak{gl}(2,\mathbb{R}) \mid \mbox{tr}(X) = 0 \right\}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that function $$V\ni X \mapsto q(X) := \mbox{tr}(XDX^{T}),$$ where $$D=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ is a quadratic form. Then reduce $q$ to a canonical form and calculate its signature.

---

Edited:
I do not know if my procedure it's correct. I wrote $q(X)$ in the following way
$$q(X)= tr(XDX^T)=tr \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2\\ x_3 & -x_1
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_3\\ x_2 & -x_1
\end{pmatrix}=x_1x_2+x_3^2-x_2^2-x_1x_3.$$
Now we form a symmetric matrix
$$q(X)= \begin{pmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & -1/2 \\
1/2 & -1 & 0\\
-1/2 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}.$$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are
$$\lambda_1=0 \ \ \ \lambda_2=-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \ \ \ \lambda_3=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}},$$
then, the signature is
$$\sigma(q)=(1,1,1).$$
Is this right?

Comment: You need to multiply a 2x2 matrix $X$ in $XDX^{\top}$

Comment: I see... that's why I feel some weird about my procedure

Comment: I'd suggest writing out a simple basis for $V=gl(2,\mathrm{R})| tr(X)=0$ and thinking about what the dimension has to do with the signature.  Then using your symmetrized $ \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$ figure out the symmetric bilinear form $\langle X,Y\rangle$.  From here a simple guess works or compute the $3\times 3$ Gram style matrix where $g_{i,j}=\langle X_i, X_j\rangle$ and its signature (where $X_k$ refers to the kth basis vector for $V$)

Comment: What text are you using?   Your original attempt indicates that you are lost.  I outlined a solution in my above comment.  You subsequently accepted as correct an answer that is obviously wrong on dimension grounds.  Ref either of my two prior comments.  If your current text is confusing I can recommend another but there is more than one major issue here.

Comment: I'm using Hoffman and Kunze but this particular exercise I found it in the internet... I thought it was easy. Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: In fact I was confused about the $gl(2,\mathbb{R})$. it stands for the invertible matrices with dimension 2x2 right?

Comment: what $gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ stands for depends on context...  How could $gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ possibly stand for a vector space of invertible matrices?  Said vector space must contain the zero matrix which is never invertible under multiplication. (There's actually a notation difference between $gl(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ re: Lie algebras vs groups but it seems prudent to focus on basics of what a vector space is instead.) I'm partial to the Bilinear Forms chapter in Artin's *Algebra* though the bilinear/quadratic forms chapter in *Linear Algebra Done Wrong* may be more your speed.

Comment: Thanks for the time for the answer, I would check those books.

Comment: And I would edit my post.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to work with the columns of $X$ rather than with its entries.

Answer (score 3):

You must take X=
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & -a \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then trace XDX^t works out to ab-b^2 +c^2 -ca which is homogeneous and hence a quadratic form. The matrix of the quadratic form is
$$
 \begin{bmatrix} 
 0 & 1/2 & -1/2\\ 
 1/2 & -1 & 0\\ 
  -1/2 & 0 &1\\
 \end{bmatrix} 
$$ whose signature is 0 and rank 2

Answer (score 1):

More generally, given $n \times n$ matrix $\bf A$,

$$\begin{aligned} q ({\bf X}) := \mbox{tr} \left( {\bf X} {\bf A} {\bf X}^\top \right) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \langle {\bf x}_i, {\bf x}_j \rangle \\ &= (\mbox{vec} ({\bf X}))^\top \left( {\bf A} \otimes {\bf I}_n \right) \mbox{vec} ({\bf X}) \\ &= (\mbox{vec} ({\bf X}))^\top \left( \left(\frac{ {\bf A} + {\bf A}^\top}{2}\right) \otimes {\bf I}_n \right) \mbox{vec} ({\bf X}) \end{aligned}$$

where ${\bf x}_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of $\bf X$, $\mbox{vec}$ denotes the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator and $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). The eigenvalues of

$$ \left(\frac{ {\bf A} + {\bf A}^\top}{2}\right) \otimes {\bf I}_n  $$

are the eigenvalues of the *symmetric* part of $\bf A$ but with algebraic multiplicity multiplied by $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

For an arbitrary matrix
$\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\v&w\end{array}\right]$
the quadratic form is
$${\rm tr}\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\v&w\end{array}\right]^{\top}
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&-1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\v&w\end{array}\right]\right)=
x^2+y^2+xv+yw-v^2-w^2,$$
that can be translated to
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x&y&v&w
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\y\\v\\w
\end{array}
\right)
=
x^2+y^2+xv+yw-v^2-w^2.$$

Such quadratic form has signature $(+,+,-,-)$.

Comment: $\dim V = 3\lt 4 $ so the signature cannot sum to 4.  Further $\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}2 & 1\\1 & -2\end{matrix}\right]$  is a null vector so the form is degenerate.

Comment: @user8675309 good catch!

Comment: Thank you that's what I did... I was confused about the $X$.

Comment: still my response is not making use of the trace restriction

Comment: How's that? You used the trace in the first part, didn't you?

Comment: The diagonal elements of $X$ must sum to 0. Let $w=-x$ and reformulate the last quadratic form.